# Proper up/back behavior after selecting from menu

Tags: android

I'm learning Android, and I just completed the Kotlin Fundamentals lesson where you build a little trivia game app with a navigation controller and a navigation drawer.

[image]

#### `navigation.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/titleFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/titleFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigation.TitleFragment"
        android:label="fragment_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_title">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_titleFragment_to_gameFragment"
            app:destination="@id/gameFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/gameFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigation.GameFragment"
        android:label="GameFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_game">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_gameFragment_to_gameOverFragment"
            app:destination="@id/gameOverFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/gameFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_gameFragment_to_gameWonFragment"
            app:destination="@id/gameWonFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/gameFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/gameOverFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigation.GameOverFragment"
        android:label="fragment_game_over"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_game_over">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_gameOverFragment_to_gameFragment"
            app:destination="@id/gameFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/titleFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/gameWonFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigation.GameWonFragment"
        android:label="fragment_game_won"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_game_won">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_gameWonFragment_to_gameFragment"
            app:destination="@id/gameFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/titleFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigation.AboutFragment"
        android:label="fragment_about"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/rulesFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigation.RulesFragment"
        android:label="fragment_rules"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_rules" />
</navigation>
```

#### `MainActivity.kt`

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val navController get() = findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, drawerLayout)
}
```

The lesson includes navigation from fragment to fragment, including custom `popUpTo` for actions, as well as a navigation drawer.

However, there is a "bug" that isn't handled in the lesson: When you start a game, and then navigate to About or Rules from the drawer, the up/back takes you to the home page, not back to the game, which is then gone.

How could you fix this behavior so that the drawer pages go back/up to the actual previous page?